# Why did sort not return this list in numerical order?

Tags: python, sorting

i have the following problem with this code in Python when i try to simply sort out some numbers and here is the code.

```
array = input().split(" ")

between_numbers = " <= ".join(sorted(array))

print(between_numbers)
```

With this given input:

`-100 500 36724 -673 874 37 36 324 627 82 76537 -772 -936 2467 2365 -3763`

I got this:

`-100 <= -3763 <= -673 <= -772 <= -936 <= 2365 <= 2467 <= 324 <= 36 <= 36724 <= 37 <= 500 <= 627 <= 76537 <= 82 <= 874`

instead of this:

`-3763 <= -936 <= -772 <= -673 <= -100 <= 36 <= 37 <= 82 <= 324 <= 500 <= 627 <= 874 <= 2365 <= 2467 <= 36724 <= 76537`

Can someone tell me why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`split` gives you a list of strings. Strings are by default compared lexicographically:

```
"a" < "aardvark" < "b"
"1" < "10" < "2"
```

If you had a list of *numbers*, or if you specify the sorting key to be the `int` conversion, `sorted` would do what you want. Thus, either

```
array = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
```

or

```
between_numbers = " <= ".join(sorted(array, key=int))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response and for that clarification!

Answer (score 0):

convert each number into Integer and then sort

```
array = [int(i) for i in input.split(' ')]
```

you will get sorted list according to numbers not according string(this is happening in your case)

Answer (score -1):

x = np.array([2, 1, 4, 3, 5])
np.sort(x)
you can use this